# How to loop through Google Map coordinates?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm stuck trying to loop through this array of GPS coordinates that puts pins on the google map.

Here is my code: http://pastie.org/466369

The problem is on **line 27-36**.

If I change it to the following, it will place 1 pin on that exact location, but I want it to loop through the array so I can add multiple pins:

```
//var markers = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        var point = new GLatLng(39.729308,-121.854087);
        marker = new GMarker(point);
        map.addOverlay(marker);
        markers[i] = marker;
    }
```

Anyone know why this version below is breaking?

```
var markers = [
(39.729308,-121.854087),
(39.0,-121.0)
];

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var point = new GLatLng(markers[i]);
    marker = new GMarker(point);
    map.addOverlay(marker);
    markers[i] = marker;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the following code is incorrect JavaScript.

```
var markers = [
(39.729308,-121.854087),
(39.0,-121.0)
];
```

you probably meant to do this:

```
var markers = [
[39.729308,-121.854087],
[39.0,-121.0]
];
```

Secondly, according to the documentation [`GLatLng` takes two parameters](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GLatLng), not an array.

Try this instead:

```
var point = new GLatLng(markers[i][0], markers[i][1]);
```

**Edit**

I've corrected your code and hosted it on JS Bin. It seems to be working after fixing the aforementioned issues:

http://jsbin.com/afojo

Comment: Instead of using GLatLng, do you know a way to use Geocodes? Just curious..

like if I did:

var markers = [[624 Nord Ave, Chico CA]];

geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
var point = new geocoder.getLocations(markers);

or something of that sort?

Comment: Google's API Code Playground as some great examples and source code: 

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=maps#map_geocoding_simple